# Ohhh Noo !!! Getting Core Dump in the Following program in C

Tags: c

this is my code I am using in Unix machine, using gcc compiler

```
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int nr = 0, nc = 0;
    printf("Enter number of coulmns:");
    scanf("%d", &nc);
    printf("Enter number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &nr);
    int *x ,temp;
    printf("Enter the matrix:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nc; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            *(x + i * nc + j) = temp;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nc; j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", *( x + i * nc + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It takes number of rows and number of coulmns properly. But, I am getting coredump as soon as I enter first integer input to the matrix. Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: where did you initialize `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised that produces a core dump. line 10 declared a pointer that points to nowhere -- there is no memory allocated to it. If `x` is supposed to be an array then use `malloc()` to allocate memory for the array `x = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));` will allocate an array of 10 integers.

Answer (score 3):

You never allocate room, so you just use `x`, an uninitialized pointer, and write stuff whereever it happens to be pointing. Totally undefined behavior.

You must use `malloc()` to initialize it to point at valid memory:

```
x = malloc(nr * nc * sizeof *x);
```

Also, check that the allocation succeeds, and before that check that the `scanf()`s succeed. I/O and memory allocation are both "fragile" classes of operations that can fail.

Then, there's no need for the `temp`, you can scan directly into the matrix in the loop:

```
scanf("%d", x + i * nc + j);
```

Again, that can fail too so you should handle that instead of just assuming it works.

Comment: @unwinfd koodo fix the error by sanjog's ans and also you give the correct answer thanks from my side

Comment: @MrVaivav Glad to help. I (of course) think my answer is better since it allocates the proper amount of space for your case, and doesn't repeat the type name. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
*(x+i*nc+j)=temp;
```

You haven't allocated memory for x pointer.